# Is “destroyer of hope” same as “bringer of hopelessness”?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Got redirected here from Philosophy SE :https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/40907/ to ask here for an more technical discussion and comparison of the two phrases.

Are two phrases equivalent?

On similar lines, "destroyer of life" vs "bringer of death".

Edit1:
The usage was attributing something as "bringer of hopelessness".
Then somebody used "destroyer of hope" interchangeably with the above phrase leading to the discussion if the 2 are equivalent.

I am trying to reason for any distinction (or lack thereof) by drawing a parallel with "life" to see if it helps.

I understand that philosophical aspects of the concept of "life" and "hope" (and lack therefor) are better suited to Philosophy SE and but literal meanings and usage of phrases(and using them interchangeably) possibly belongs here?

Comment: No and no. A "destroyer" of something extinguishes it. A "bringer" of something creates it. There is a difference between a murderer and terminal cancer, for instance; one "destroys" life, and the other "brings" death. One has sentient intention; the other does not. "Hope" and "hopelessness" are too vague to be considered here on EL&U.

Comment: @MarkHubbard: Does "creating death" make sense? Isn't it more like "removal or destruction of life" resulting in "absence of life"? Similarly, isn't "creating hopelessness" actually "removal or destruction of hope" resulting in "absence of hope"?

Comment: "Creating death" does not make much sense, in my opinion. And how does one "create hopelessness"? Your question should be edited to improve it by explaining how you would *use* the distinction in your writing and/or speech. This is a forum for English Language and *Usage.* If your question does not involve one or the other, then it is considered off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

A “destroyer of hope”  does not always become a  "bringer of hopelessness”
A person or people can have "hope" destroyed without acquiring "hopelessness".
"A destroyer of all hope" would become a   "bringer of hopelessness”

> Hope: Grounds for believing that something good may happen ([OD0](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hope))

Hope may mean something more than a single feeling. So, "all hope" may not be destroyed by a  “destroyer of hope”.

A  "destroyer of life" does become a  "bringer of death", as death occurs when even one life is destroyed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Great point with regards to usage of "destroyer of all hope".
As an aside, would you also argue "destroying all hope" is interchangeable with "taking all hope"?

Comment: Not interchangeable, but similar. One can take hope, and give it back. When hope is destroyed, it is gone.